# Match with OR condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

been playing around with cypher for a while now and having a bit of difficulty understanding something.

assuming i have person nodes some of which might have a belongs_to relationship 
what would be the best way to find a node that either

- does **not** have a blongs_to relationship but does have an email address
  of "x@x.xom"
- OR
- does have a belongs_to relationship with a Id Property of "100" ( the property is of the relationship)

i have managed to create some queries that return the expected data, but i don't know if those are ones that are "correct" in the long run of my cypher understanding

any help would be appreciated.  ( specifically with regards to And | Or , order and efficiency )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this?

You can use path patterns as predicates, see: http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/query-where.html#query-where-patterns

```
MATCH (n:Person {email:"x@x.com"})
WHERE NOT (n)-[:BELONGS_TO]->() OR (n)-[:BELONGS_TO {id:100})->()
RETURN n
```

Comment: many thanks for the answer itself.   Other than those docs would you also point me to performance related query topics.    ( i very much hope to solving for later ( when i do have a million nodes :)  )

Comment: i also have same query

Comment: I need very similar query BUT I have to make some filtering on edge properties as well. I need some things like `MATCH (n:Person)-[r1:BELONGS_TO]->() OR (n)-[r2:HEY_TO]->()
WHERE r1.date < 1 and r2.date > 10
RETURN n`  How could I do that ? I think I find it `[r1:BELONGS_TO|HEY_TO]`